# How to display camera preview in gridview's first item in android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working on a gallery app wherein I have to display all the images from the gallery to `gridview` . I have done it successfully, but i also want to display the camera preview in the first grid item of the `gridView`. Can any buddy please help me to do this?

my code is as below:

```
/**
 * Created by netclues on 4/26/16.
 */
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);


        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_camera);
        thumbnails[0] =icon;
        arrPath[0] = "image1";
        for (int i = 1; i < this.count; i++) {

            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);


        }
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();
    }





    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.imageview.setId(position);

//            holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//
//                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    int id;
//                    id = v.getId();
//                    if (id==0) {
//                        System.out.print("Idpath" + id);
//                    }else {
//                        Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this,
//                                lastscreen.class);
//                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
//                                "image/*");
//                        intent.putExtra("path", arrPath[id]);
//
//                        startActivity(intent);
//                    }
//                }
//            });
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to add a TextureView to your layout, and send the camera preview to the TextureView. SurfaceView can be a bit more tricky.

Comment: @fadden - Can u help me for this deaR?